# Find first n summed values in Excel with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

Sheet 'raw':

```
Account  | Value
A          2
A          3
B          5
C          2
A          1
B          4
D          8
F          18
D          4
```

What I would like to capture the top n accounts by sum of values using only Excel formulas:

Sheet2:

```
Top   | Account  | Sum
1       F          18
2       D          12
3       B          9
4       A          6
4       C          2
```

I tried this approach (considering A to C columns in Excel):
- for the value:

```
{=LARGE(ROUND(raw!B$2:B$65000,2)+ROW(raw!B$2:B$65000)/10000),A2)}
```

- for the account name:

  `{=INDEX(raw!$A$2:$A$65000,MATCH(A2,(ROUND(raw!B$2:B$65000,2)+ROW(raw!B$2:B$65000)/10000),0))}`

I use array formulas for that, but it will provide me the top individual values not the sum per account

Could someone help me on this topic?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not use a pivot table and sort by the data value?

Comment: That's not what I want, sorry.. That's a easy fix and I need a formula instead

Comment: Can you accept a solution that adds a helper column to the `raw` table data ?

Comment: Depends on the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your dataset following seems to work:

In cell C2, **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** and not just **ENTER** following formula:

`=LARGE((ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,0))*SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10),ROWS($C$2:$C2))`

In cell B2, **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** and not just **ENTER** following formula:

`=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,MATCH(Sheet2!C2,(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10)=MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$10,0))*SUMIF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10),0))`

Edit: There's typo in the formula Sheet2!D2 should be Sheet2!C2.Above formula is corrected.

**CAUTION:** Formula may give incorrect results if totals tie.

Comment: @rosuandreimihai There was a typo in the second formula. I have uploaded Demo file https://www.dropbox.com/s/49tz39tarvn43eu/SO_47459367.xlsx?dl=0